# Refile Production Error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, refile

In dev my rails app works just fine.

In production instead there is just no image, it's uploaded to the server but it just won't show up. I'm using the default backend.

When accessing the image url directly all I see is "error". :(

Hope somebody could give me a hint.

Comment: Whats in the production.log file?

Comment: Not enough information for anyone to say anything. In production your errors aren't shown to the browser, you have to check your log/production.log. Although if the request isn't even making it that far, you may need to check your web server logs. You should also tell us what app server or other mechanism you are using to deploy.

Comment: Not much to go on. Did you pre-recompile your assets for production before deploy?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy there are no errors in the production.log. That's why I'm asking :/

Comment: @jrochkind I'm using capistrano. But it's no problem of assets. I got the problem when uploading files to the server with the refile gem. Refile uses a rack middleware to manage files. That's where the problem is, I'm able to upload files (images) but not able to Retriever back since I get an error only saying "error".

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Although imagemagick was installed, I was missing GraphicsMagick.

```
App 16260 stderr: Refile::App: Error -> ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed
```